# ScrollMagic - Stop scrolling behaviour until animation is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollmagic

I want to prevent my users to scroll for ages just to be sure the animation finishes, so my question is, are there any events like "onStart" / "onComplete" for the animation, so I could stop the scrolling behaviour with `overflow: hidden;` on the body until the animation is done and remove that afterwards?

I checked the (old) gsap Docs and there are onStart/onComplete Events either for TweenMax.to and TimelineMax - I tried using them, but they fired immediately after page-load and I don't know why.

(https://greensock.com/docs/v2/TimelineMax/TimelineMax())

(https://greensock.com/docs/v2/TweenMax/static.to())

I'm animating svg-Font to achieve a "draw"-like feeling on the page.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yf89Lhzv/1/

(Hello World should be fully animated until the user can scroll again)

Comment: GreenSock doesn't recommend ScrollMagic. Instead they recommend the official scroll plugin: [ScrollTrigger](https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger/)! It's better in every way.

Comment: @ZachSaucier thank you for your comment, but I don't know if I have enough time to rewrite the whole thing. I need to be done in the evening of 24th.

Comment: I'd guess it'd take you a shorter amount of time